# Is there any efficiency gain in writing the 99% case first in an if loop?

Tags: python, performance

I have some Python code that evaluates a file line by line like this:

```
def evaluate_file():
  firstline = True
  for line in lines:
    if firstline:
      # do something with the first line
      firstline = False
    else
      # do something else
```

99% of the time, what's being looked at is *not* the first line. Is there any efficiency improvement to writing the 99% case first, i.e., the first if statement is `if !firstline`?

Comment: you can measure it by using timeit() function.

Comment: why would you structure it that way at all? `lines` is already a list/sequence. you can use `lines[0]` and then `lines[1:]` (in separate functions if needed).

Comment: I don't know the state of python branch prediction, but I was always under the impression that an if statement that has the same outcome 99% of the time will be optimized.

That said; try it out. Run a little experiment and see if it makes any difference in execution time with large files.

Comment: Does python even have a branch predictor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote up a quick little test, probably not perfect, but here goes.

Results, based on **1,109,890 lines** of data and 100 executions:

- ifTest: 0.0472489972114563 seconds
- arrayTest: 0.06530603981018067 seconds
- flipIfTest: 0.04617302393913269 seconds

The perfomance gain you get by doing the suggested change is rather small but worth it.

Although the arrayTest was the slowest, I'd still prefer it as it feels bit more intuitive.

Code:

```
import time

def ifTest(lines): 
    count = 0
    firstline = True
    for line in lines:
        if firstline:
            firstline = False
        else:
            count = count + 1
    return count

def arrayTest(lines):
    count = 0
    firstline = lines[0]
    for line in lines[1:]:
        count = count + 1
    return count

def flipIfTest(lines):
    count = 0
    firstline = True
    for line in lines:
        if not firstline:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            firstline = False
    return count

f = open("data.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()

runs = 100

avg = 0
for i in range(0,runs):
    start = time.time()
    res = ifTest(lines)
    end = time.time()
    print("Lines Read: {}, Time: {}".format(res, end - start))
    avg = avg + (end - start)
avg = avg / runs
print("ifTest: {}".format(avg))

avg = 0
for i in range(0,runs):
    start = time.time()
    res = arrayTest(lines)
    end = time.time()
    print("Lines Read: {}, Time: {}".format(res, end - start))
    avg = avg + (end - start)
avg = avg / runs
print("arrayTest: {}".format(avg))

avg = 0
for i in range(0,runs):
    start = time.time()
    res = flipIfTest(lines)
    end = time.time()
    print("Lines Read: {}, Time: {}".format(res, end - start))
    avg = avg + (end - start)
avg = avg / runs
print("flipIfTest: {}".format(avg))
```

Comment: You should use timeit for this kind of test.  I'm getting slightly different results (with arrayTest being faster).   Example use: `from timeit import timeit` `t = timeit(lambda:arrayTest(lines), number=100)`

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's more to the use-case (which would require updating the question with [mcve]), why use conditional to identify the "first" line, when you can just slice `lines` and do what you need with the first one, and then something else with the rest of them?

```
def evaluate_file():
  # evaluate the first line:
  # do something with ``lines[0]``

  for line in lines[1:]
      # do some
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference would be insignificant if your 1% condition is merely "first line".  What would save time would be to perform the 1% outside of the loop and then loop on the subsequent items unconditionally.  This will save the 99% useless testing for the first line condition and, more importantly, it will improve the legibility of your code (if only by reducing the indenting levels).

Using an iterator is an efficient way of doing this separation.  For example:

```
iLines =iter(lines)
for line in iLines:
    # do something with the first line
    break 
for line in iLines:
    # do something else with other lines
```

This will work with lists and with sources that cannot be indexed or sliced.  It will also allow for more complex "first part" conditions that may need to skip more than one initial item.

If the code to perform for the first line is "in addition" to common code for all lines, it may be easier to use enumerate instead of a flag variable (although it is marginally slower):

```
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if i==0:
       # do something special for the first line
    # common code for all lines
```

You could also use the iterator approach and place the common code in a function that you call in both cases.

Comment: Instead of `breaking` in the first loop you could use `itertools.islice` to separate `lines` into an iterator for the first line and an iterator for the rest of the lines.  Keeping the loops though will allow you to gracefully deal with degenerate cases like files with no lines.  If you would rather error in such cases you could replace the first `for` loop with `first_line = next(iLines)` followed by whatever code you need to do for the first line.

Comment: Thank you. I moved the `first_line` code outside the loop.